# Update information in a Hash associated to an ActiveRecord rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have an two hashes where one is called `current_savings` and one called `mambu_repayments`

```
current_savings.select {|s| s[:status] == 'repaid' }
```

In **`rails c`** the above will output any savings where status is repaid.

```
mambu_repayments.last
```

In **rails c** the above line will output the repayment. This hash has key value element `"state"=>"PAID"`

I want change that state value to COMPLETE for every last repayment where current_savings status is marked repaid.

In my relevant controller I have tried the following:

```
 # check saving is not nil and status is :repaid.
    # Retrieve last repayment from @repayments and check if it has status PAID

    if current_savings != nil? && current_savings.status == 'repaid'
      mambu_repayments = current_savings.get_repayments_with_parents.select{|s| s["state"] == 'PAID'}
      mambu_repayments.last = 'COMPLETE'
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the below snippet

```
# check saving is not nil and status is :repaid.

# Retrieve last repayment from @repayments and check if it has status PAID

if current_savings != nil? && current_savings.status == 'repaid'
  mambu_repayments = current_savings.get_repayments_with_parents.select{|s| s["state"] == 'PAID'}
  # If you dont' want to run callbacks and validations
  mambu_repayments.last.update_columns(state: 'COMPLETE') 
  # If you want to run callbacks and validations
  # mambu_repayments.last.update(state: 'COMPLETE') 
end
```